# FineUploader.js - How to access S3 policy document signature?

Tags: fine-uploader

**Purpose:** In order to confirm with the server that the image was uploaded to the S3 bucket successfully, I would like to send the policy document signature back to the server. My policy document includes a key randomly generated server-side (this way a malicious user can't overwrite another user's uploads by deliberately using a duplicate key), and a corresponding row is temporarily created in the database marked as "pending". If the correct policy document signature does not come back to the server before the expiry, that means that the upload may have been abandoned, so the server may try to delete any file with that key from the bucket and then delete the temporary database row.

**Question:** I intend to include the policy document signature in [`uploadSuccess.params`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#uploadSuccess.params). To accomplish this, how can the policy document signature be accessed?

---

Possibly relevant snippet of [source code](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/file-uploader/5.10.0/s3.jquery.fine-uploader/s3.jquery.fine-uploader.js), but I don't know how to "reach" `responseJson` and use it (assuming this is where the signature is contained):

```
function handleSignatureReceived(id, xhrOrXdr, isError) {
    var responseJson = xhrOrXdr.responseText,
        pendingSignatureData = pendingSignatures[id],
        promise = pendingSignatureData.promise,
        signatureConstructor = pendingSignatureData.signatureConstructor,
        errorMessage, response;
```

Comment: Please don't change a question this drastically, especially one with answers. I suggest you roll back your edit and post a new question instead.

Comment: Done, here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340503/fineuploader-s3-methods-to-expose-policy-document

Answer (score 0):

The response passed to your onComplete callback handler is the response from s3 when the upload completes, as expected. There is no good reason to track the exact signature. If you want to know if the upload failed or succeeded, check for the success property in the response.

Comment: But it's not signed, so it's vulnerable to tampering by malicious users?

Comment: I don't follow. The request you are sending to s3 _is_ signed.

Comment: The request sent back to the uploadSuccess endpoint isn't signed, is it? So that means the user could tamper with that request, i.e. change the key. I want to include the policy document signature so that the server can decode the key from there, which is [almost] guaranteed to not have been tampered with.

Comment: You cannot decode a signed request. The signature is generated using a one-way hashing algorithm.

Comment: Ah I see, that's why S3 requires both the signed and unsigned version... so that's what I'll have to do as well, the user sends both versions back and I check to make sure it matches the signature. So, would this be feasible with fineuploader? Or do you think that this is pointless?

Comment: I'm not certain what you are trying to protect. I would just use the UUID of the file to match your record in the DB. On uploadSuccess, send this UUID. Otherwise, presumably you have a service to clear out old DB records.

Comment: Hi Ray, I changed the question significantly, would you please take another look if/when you have time? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidTan Please don't change a question this drastically, especially one with answers. I suggest you roll back your edit and post a new question instead.